# XForms processor for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, xforms

Does there exist any XForms processor tool for Delphi?

Ie. a tool that parses a XForms-document and builds a corresponding GUI.

#### Update to clarify:

I'm talking about this kind of XForms:

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XForms)
- [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/xforms/)
- [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xforms/xforms_intro.asp)
- [about.com](http://webdesign.about.com/library/weekly/aa091701a.htm)

And instead of generating [HTML forms](http://www.w3schools.com/xforms/tryit_xapp.asp?filename=try_form), I would like to generate Delphi VCL forms...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that it was a project called XFormPlayer Engine, but now the project is dead/unavailable. Here is a discussion with the same subject

http://www.delphigroups.info/2/7/276234.html

From what I saw, it seems that if you want to use some tool, you need to write your own.

Best regards,
Radu

Comment: Yes, I saw that discussion :-(   ...among a lot of deprecated web sites on the topic.  I assumed that I had to write my own, but had to double check with the SO-community that I didn't miss anything...

Comment: I think this would be an excellent project, Jørn.  Except that everything on the web points to this being a dead or dying technology.  It was started as web tech, and is finding very low adoption out there on the web. If it had achieved "critical mass" in the web community, surely a Delphi project would be a great follow-up.

Comment: @Warren.  I know...   But I happen to have about 100-150 large and up-to-date XForms specifications lying around.  Aprox 500-700 TForms :-/.  Would be nice to have some code generation tool to help out :-P.   I look forward, though, to create such a tool :-D  But it would have been a wast of time if someone already did it...

Comment: Well then, for you alone, this would be a great tool, and if you open source it, surely it will find other users and you'll hopefully get some help with maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

You mean classical Unix X-Forms ? With fdesign files? Free Pascal has a port and a converter for that (and it will almost certainly work in Delphi, maybe changing one thing to remove a @ here and there).

See fpc/packages/xforms/src/fd2pascal.pp in Free Pascal SVN.

Comment: No sorry, not _that_ kind of XForms.  _This_ kind of XForms: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xforms

Comment: Related to X11 yes. But back then it was a separate package, more like GTK/QT now.